# Send a response to Angular.js in Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

Im using Angular with Node and would to send a response to the client-side controller from a GET request.

The line of code Im using to send the response seems not to be working when I use native Node as opposed to Express.js

Here is my angular controller:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('/test').then(function(response){ 

            $scope = response.data;

        });

});
```

This is routed to essentially the following server script:

```
http.createServer(function onRequest(req, res){ 

    if(req.method==='GET'){

        var scope = 'this is the test scope';

        res.json(scope); // TypeError: res.json is not a function           
    }   

}).listen(port);
```

res.json() throws an error unless I use an express server

```
var app = express();

app.all('/*', function(req, res) {

    if(req.method==='GET'){

        var scope = 'this is the test scope';

        res.json(scope); // OK!         
    }

 }).listen(port);
```

I was pretty sure the json() function came with node. How do I send a response back to angular when using a native Node server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.json` is not in the API for [HTTP response](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

The standard way would be to use `res.write()` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)) and then `res.end()` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback)). But in your case, since you're not sending a lot of data you can use a shortcut and just use `res.end()` with a `data` parameter :)

Comment: ah! so simple. I also had to stringify the json data: res.end(JSON.stringify(context));